# Disabling mouse events on GeoJSON particular feature on load

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am using geoJson coordinates for creating boundaries around the countries in Leaflet.

I am also filling the country with some colors and then showing marker on those countries which have data.

My concern is, can i disable mouse events on some countries(feature) which doesn't have data?

Comment: You can achieve that by using the onEachFeature click function - `if (e.target.properties['your_data']) {}`

Comment: Thanks. but if you can give me any example then it would be great help!!